# Запросы на сайты HttpWebRequest и HttpWebResponse

Tags: vb.net, http

Здравствуйте.

На VB.net мне нужно отсылать запросы на сайты и получать, ответы кодами 200, 403, 404. Пользуюсь HttpWebRequest и HttpWebResponse, но в 403 и 404 случае просто вылетает, а мне нужен ответ в виде числа (403, 404, 200).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

> Класс HttpWebRequest создает исключение WebException в случае возникновения ошибки при доступе к интернет-ресурсам. Свойство WebException.Status содержит значение WebExceptionStatus, которое указывает на источник ошибки. Когда WebException.Status равно WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError, свойство Response содержит HttpWebResponse, принятый из ресурса.

Проверяйте статус исключения на ProtocolError, и если это так, то извлекайте ответ из свойства Response.